# How to pass textarea to variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am new to react . i have a code that create problems using textarea. i need to make a table that saves the title and the problem description which were inserted in the textarea . but I don't seem to succeed to collect whats inside the textarea.
here's ,y code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../styles/styles.css";
import BlockInput from "../pages/blockInput";

class CreateProblem extends Component {
 change = () => {
   
   var text = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;

   document.getElementById("col1").innerHTML = text;
 };
 changetwo = () => {
  
   var z = document.getElementById("problem").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("col2").innerHTML = z;
 };

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
     <h3>Enter the problem title : </h3>
           <textarea
               id="title"
               name="textValue"
               onChange={this.handleChange}
               className="item"
             ></textarea>
             <button onClick={this.change}> OK </button>
         
             <h3>Enter the problem description : </h3>
             <div>
               {" "}
               <textarea
                 id="problem"
                 name="textValue"
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                 className="problemDescribe"
               >
                 {" "}
               </textarea>
               <button onClick={this.changetwo}> OK </button>
             </div>

             <h3> Add new blocks</h3>
             {" "}
             <BlockInput />
             <h4 id="seed">1</h4>
                   
       <table className="table">
         <th>
           <td id="col1"></td>
         </th>
         <th>
           <td>
             <div id="col2"> </div>
           </td>
         </th>
       </table>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default CreateProblem;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../styles/styles.css";
import BlockInput from "../pages/blockInput";

class CreateProblem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      _title: "",
      title: "",
      _problem: "",
      problem: "",
    };
  }

  const change = () => {
    this.setState({ title: _title });
  };
  const changetwo = () => {
    this.setState({ problem: _problem });
  };
  render() {
       return (
     <div>
     <h3>Enter the problem title : </h3>
           <textarea
               id="title"
               name="textValue"
               onChange={(e) => this.setState({ _title: e.target.value })}}
               className="item"
             ></textarea>
             <button onClick={this.change}> OK </button>
             <h3>Enter the problem description : </h3>
             <div>
               {" "}
               <textarea
                 id="problem"
                 name="textValue"
                 onChange={(e) => this.setState({_problem: e.target.value})}
                 className="problemDescribe"
               >
                 {" "}
               </textarea>
               <button onClick={this.changetwo}> OK </button>
             </div>
             <h3> Add new blocks</h3>
             {" "}
             <BlockInput />
             <h4 id="seed">1</h4>
       <table className="table">
         <th>
           <td id="col1">{this.state.title}</td>
         </th>
         <th>
           <td>
             <div id="col2">{this.state.problem}</div>
           </td>
         </th>
       </table>
     </div>
       );
  }
}

export default CreateProblem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your textArea component has this **onChange={this.handleChange}** method that would deal with changes in that element, but you are not using the value of the text box anywhere.

I suggest you use a State to store that information so that you can use it properly.

Try:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../styles/styles.css";
import BlockInput from "../pages/blockInput";

class CreateProblem extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {title: '', description: ''};
  }

 change = (field) => (value) => {
   this.setState({...this.state, this.state[field]: value});
 };


 render() {
   return (
     <div>
     <h3>Enter the problem title : </h3>
           <textarea
               id="title"
               name="textValue"
               onChange={this.handleChange}
               value={this.state.title}
               className="item"
             ></textarea>
             <button onClick={this.change}> OK </button>
         
             <h3>Enter the problem description : </h3>
             <div>
               {" "}
               <textarea
                 id="problem"
                 name="textValue"
                 value={this.state.description}
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                 className="problemDescribe"
               >
                 {" "}
               </textarea>
               <button onClick={this.changetwo}> OK </button>
             </div>

             <h3> Add new blocks</h3>
             {" "}
             <BlockInput />
             <h4 id="seed">1</h4>
                   
       <table className="table">
         <th>
           <td id="col1"></td>
         </th>
         <th>
           <td>
             <div id="col2"> </div>
           </td>
         </th>
       </table>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default CreateProblem;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { id: "", problemDesc: "" };
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log("problemDesc", e.target.value);
    this.setState({ problemDesc: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <textarea onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
        <br />
        {this.state.problemDesc} //see the updated value here
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo :- https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-wcy2h?file=/src/App.js